# Pinterest API for Conversions

Tags: pinterest, pinterest-api

I'm trying to request access to this API by following their instructions:

https://developers.pinterest.com/blog/2022/04/12/introducing-pinterest-api-v5/

[image: beta feature instructions]

Note, that the location in the help does not exist. I went for "Pinterest API and Developer Tools > API Access".

However, the response from filling in the form was:

> Hello there, we could not complete your request because '' appears to be an invalid
> advertiser ID. Please enter the correct ID in the Advertiser ID field in the left-hand pane on this page and then
> change this ticket back to OPEN.

The form I filled in did not ask for an "advertiser ID" and it is not relevant. There was no link for "this page", and there seems to be no way to find the "ticket".

Has anyone managed to make a request for access? If so, how?

Or does anyone know how to find their tickets?

Comment: Hi Tony, I am looking into this..

Comment: This API has moved from beta to GA, you should have access without needing to submit this form. Apologies for the confusion.